# How to Fix different text align in button because of i tag

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

[image: example]

You can see that 'create' is near the top while 'project' is in the middle. And heights are also different even though I have never given height. When I delete i tag, 'project' and 'create' are both same vertical align. I think the problem is because of i tag, but I don't have idea how can I fix it. I want to make 'project' and 'create' both are placed in middle of button. Please help

I already try => vertical align middle, text align center, display flex, give padding&height after wrap text with span tag

In React, JSX code

```js
    <NavLeft>
      <button>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>project
      </button>
      <button>create</button>
    </NavLeft>
```

styled component code

```js
const NavLeft = styled.div`
  ${({ theme }) => theme.flexSet()};
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;

  button {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    background-color: red;

    i {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so just set `display: flex;` on your `navLeft`.

I would also advice you to adjust the alignment of text in button by adding css as below:

```css
button{ 
  /* ADDED */
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
#navleft{
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;

  /*ADDED*/
  display:flex;
}
button {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  
  /* ADDED */
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button i {
  /*font-size: 16px;*/
  
  font-size: 60px; /* Bigger to show the diff */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="navleft">
  <button>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>project
  </button>
  <button>create</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add className="flex-container"

```css
.flex-container{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center; /* space-between, space-evenly => use according to your need */
}
```